# Plot_confusioin_matrix plot is not showing integer value instead it is showing some exponential value

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, seaborn, matplotlib-basemap, confusion-matrix

[image: Confusion Matrix]

```
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
from sklearn.metrics import plot_confusion_matrix

print('*** Test Accuracy ***',forest.score(X_test,y_test))
disp = plot_confusion_matrix(forest, X_test, y_test,
                                 display_labels=[0,1],
                                 cmap=plt.cm.Blues,
                             values_format='g'
                            )
```

As one can see , inside the confusion matrix plot , the numbers printed is not integer . required is integer value to plot.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are instructing the format using `values_format='g'`. The [format `g`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/string.html#formatspec) favors using scientific notation when the numbers are large (as in your case)

try passing `values_format='d'` or `values_format='.0f'` instead